# Adding columns in out file using php

Tags: php

I have created a file file1.out and I am entering data to it.
`$parameters` is an array containing the parameters name

```
   foreach($parameters as $name)
     {
           fwrite(file1.out,$name);
           //here I am fetching the value of the parameter $name from      database
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {  
               //getting some values and writing into the file;
             }

     }



        /*  this is giving output as 
             parameter1
              1
             parameter2
              2
             parameter3
              3
           but I want in this way

           parameter1   parameter2   parameter3
              1          2             3 */
```

Which special character needs to be written in the file to get a new column after fetching the data of a particular parameter? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You go to next line in every loop. So store them into a variable and write them to file after `foreach`

Use something like this:

```
<?php

$myfile = fopen("sample.txt", "w");

$names = '';
$values = '';

foreach($parameters as $name) {
           //fwrite(file1.out,$name);
           $names .= "$name \t";
           //here I am fetching the value of the parameter $name from      database
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $values .= $row[0] . "\t";
                //getting some values and writing into the file;
             }

}

   //Make sure to remove any \n.
   $values= str_replace("\n", '', $values);
   $names = str_replace("\n", '', $names );

   fwrite($myfile, $names . "\n" . $values);
   fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 varaibles inside the loop to build your strings and use "\t" between text to tab index them :

```
$param = ''; $vals = '';
   foreach($parameters as $name)
     {
       $param .= '\t\tparameter1\t\t';
       $vals .= '\t\t\t' . $name . '\t\t\t';
    ......
     }
```

Then write $param and $vals to the file after the for loop. You can use any number of \t until you find the suitable presentation.